# Can I make infinite Bux once I have more than 50% floors?

Tags: tiny-tower

Once I have more than half of the business floors, then when I use 1 tower bux to move in a bitizen, there is a chance greater than 50% that I will have the business for their dream job, which can provide *2* bux in return.

Is this true? It seems at this point you could constantly move new people in, get the bux from their dream job, then evict and repeat.

Has anybody gotten to this point and actually made it work?

Answer (score 5):

To be honest, a bitizen's dream job is random. Having more than 50% simply means that there's a 50% chance that the bitizen may have a dream job for a business that you have on your tower.

As new Bitizens (as of the last iPhone 3 update), are generated based on seeded IDs'.
So, you can technically do said above (move them in for bux then kick them out), but it's still a gamble. It's like rolling a [however many business floors Tiny Tower has]-sided dice, where the floors you have mean you earn a bux while those you don't lose you one.

**So yes, you can make infinite Bux doing this, but it's a gamble... *Unless you have every single floor (all apart from Residential), which then will mean you'll have a 100% of getting a bitizen you can get bux out of.***

Comment: Yes, I have every single floor and am generating 1000s of biz by evicting and hiring new bitizens into their dream jobs. Tedious, yes. But it works.